# What's the meaning of the phrase "got some big ones" in the sentence?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I happened to see this sentence in a subtitle of a movie, it said: ***"To think that you used an old man and a newbie as a decoy, you've sure got some big ones, don't you?"***. 
When i try to search the meaning of the phrase "big one", it just gives me something like: "a thousand dollars" or "an extremely large and destructive earthquake",... and i think they aren't suitable for the content in the sentence. 
What is the exactly meaning of the phrase "***got some big ones***" in this sentence?

Comment: Balls. Daring. A lot of nerve.

Comment: ...and they clang when he walks.

Comment: There's more than just bottle involved here. There's audacity. They're not just risking their own neck. They're acting wrongly. In a cavalier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big ones (balls) refers metaphorically to courage, force.

Ball  (slang)

> a. Usually in plural. A testicle.
>
> b**.** plural (frequently as a mass nou*n). *fig. and in extended use.
>
> (b) orig. U.S. Virility, (manly) power or strength; substance, force, vigour. Also: courage, determination. Cf. ballsy adj.
>
> - a1903   W. A. Henley in C. Harman R. L. Stevenson (2005) iv. 17   All eloquence and balls and brains; Heroic and also infantile.1928   D. H. Lawrence Lady Chatterley's Lover xiv. 236   You say a man's got no brain, when he's a fool... And when he's got none of that spunky wild bit of a man in him, you say he's got no balls. When he's sort of tame.1958   in H. Wentworth & S. B. Flexner Dict. Amer. Slang (1960) 17/1 (oral quot.)   That copy is too weak. Rewrite it and put ballson it!1979   Tucson (Arizona) Mag. Jan. 29/3   I told him I just can't do it that way... I suppose it took balls, but it is no more balls than anyone should have for themselves.1984   M. Amis Money 315   Just keeping a handhold and staying where you are,..even that takes tons of balls.2006   Sunday Territorian (Austral.) (Nexis) 17 Dec. 38   Making a decision like that..takes a lot of balls.

[Reddit.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532950/whats-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-got-some-big-ones-in-the-sentence)  (citing the OED)

Comment: So big ones phrase is short for "Big ones balls" , thank you for very useful answer. is this phrase used often in speaking ? or it's just used in movie ?

Comment: @user383745 - it is a slang, actually vulgar way to express the concept.

Comment: @user383745: it would be big balls or big ovaries, not big ones balls, ones is a substitute.